# disable Thunderbird 78's "Attach my Public Key"

Tags: pgp, thunderbird, openpgp

Is there a config editor option to disable automatically attaching my public OpenPGP key (`Options` → `Attach My Public Key`) in Thunderbird 78 (which embedded Enigmail addon functionality into the email program)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the Option to attach your public key can only be toggled on a per-mail basis and is set to on by default.

There is an [issue on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1654950), but currently there is no fix and I don't have any information if/when this feature will be added.

Update:
there is now an option to configure this in the config editor, for details look at: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1654950#c55